# Can I use my wireless repeater as access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I am about to move to a new student's appartment. 
The landlord provides internert access via ethernet. I don't know about any details it's just a ethernet socket in the wall, which you plug into and you're ready to go. (Or so I've been told. )
I don't want to miss the convenience of wireless access though, but don't want to buy new hardware. (student's budget)

I have wireless repeater ([TP-LINK WA860RE](http://uk.tp-link.com/download/TL-WA860RE_V1.html), hardware build EU-V1). 
Since this device can provide a wireless network with its own SSID and password, independently from the main wireless router, and also has an ethernet-port to provide wireless access to wired devices (e.g. game consoles, etc.), I figured it might also be able to work as an access point. 
However I could not figure out a way to configure the repeater in a way that would serve my purpose. (It also doesn't specify this usage in the manuals provided by the manufacturer. )
Are my assumptions completely off? If so, what am I missing?
If not, do you have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: *" However I could not figure out a way to configure the repeater in a way that would serve my purpose ... It also doesn't specify this usage in the manuals provided by the manufacturer"* -- You need to read section **4.2.1 To Set Up the Extender as an *Access Point*** in the user guide.  The guide states that there's a configuration screen to "switch (the) mode" to "access point",

Comment: You really made me wish it was that simple. Unfortunately you probably read the User Guide for one of the other hardware versions.

Comment: @sawdust: The section you are referring to exists for v2 and v4 but not for v1, which, sadly, is the one I own. I guess we can deduce, that this function is not available for v1-devices. It didn't occur to me to check manuals of other versions, so thanks, nonetheless. However I'd still be interested in learning whether this limitation is unavoidable due to hardware constraints or could possibly be fixed by a different firmware.

Comment: Blame yourself for providing the link to the V4 product page, instead of the V1 page.  If I was being paid, then I would do a more conscientious job.  Don't know about TP-Link, but it's well documented that "versions" of one model (e.g. Linksys wireless routers) would have same/similar functionality, but have completely different internal hardware.  If there's no firmware update, then you could try 3rd-party firmware e.g. https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa850re.  Otherwise for  wireless access point functionality, pay the lower cost of a wireless router instead of a WAP.

Comment: @sawdust :I am not blaming anyone. My apologies, if it sounded like that. I highly appreciate your help. As my repeater is still well within it's warranty, I decided against using 3rd-party firmware, although I considered the possibility before. I will probably go with your advice to buy a router instead. I don't want to risk breaking the device I have and then paying twice.